# Rails and Ajax request : internal server error (500)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I try to display many comments depending of an argument : are they verified, or not. I have to use AJAX, but I have this error :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/rate_verified?verified=true 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is the code,
**school.html.erb** (the link to call AJAX)

```
<%= link_to "Vérifiés (#{@count_verified})", rate_verified_path(:verified => true), remote: true %>
```

and the balise where I want to display informations

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <%= 'active' if @school.is_subscribed? %>" id="verifie"> </div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
 get "/rate_verified" => 'schools#verified_rating', as: 'rate_verified'
```

**schools_controller.rb** (the method that I called)

```
  def verified_rating
    @selected = @ratings.where(:verified => true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And **verified_rating.js.erb** (to use jquery)

```
$("#verifie").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'schools/rating', collection: @selected %>");
```

Does someone could help me to understand where is the error and why ?

**EDIT :**

Here is the log in my terminal :

```
Started GET "/rate_verified?verified=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-23 17:19:25 +0100
Processing by SchoolsController#verified_rating as JS
  Parameters: {"verified"=>"true"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
** [Raven] Event not sent due to excluded environment: development

NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:66:in `verified_rating'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  rack-pjax (0.8.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  browser (0.6.0) lib/browser/middleware.rb:51:in `run_app'
  browser (0.6.0) lib/browser/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:45:in `call'
  bullet (4.14.5) lib/bullet/rack.rb:10:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.15) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  rack-zippy (3.0.0) lib/rack-zippy.rb:55:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  sentry-raven (0.13.3) lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:8:in `require'
  bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.3.4) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.3.4) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/spring:13:in `require'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'


  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (25.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (21.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/marchardantonin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (48.9ms)
```

Comment: Look at the rails log. What is the error message there?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I don't know how to use rails log, could you explain me quickly how it work ?

Comment: Just look into your terminal window where you have launched your rails app. Trigger your ajax query that results in 500 error and then copy-paste last 50 lines from terminal window.

Comment: @Uzbekjon I've just edit my question with the log !

Comment: As you can see, the error is in `schools_controller.rb` on line 66. You are calling `.where()` method on `nil`. Make sure your model is initialized there.

Comment: @Uzbekjon Ok but it weird, I already use .where method on ratings in show method for school ...

Comment: I guess the `@ratings` instance variable is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what you need is in log. You have `NoMethodError (undefined method 'where' for nil:NilClass):` 
so it means that you don't have @ratings in this action in controller.
Even if you have @ratings in `school.html.erb` view, it does not means that you have them in `verified_rating` action. Add some before_action to select them again or send more params in Ajax and do it on model

```
Rating.where(some_filer: some_params, verified: true).all
```